# Вывод данных на экран с базы

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь освоить PHP и естественно возникают определенные трудности. Вот сам код:

```
<?php 
require_once('dbconfig.php'); \\ подключение базы

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `article`"); 
if ($result = false) echo "Ошибка соединения"; 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['id_article'] . '<br>'; 
    echo $row['title'] . '<br>'; 
    echo $row['content'] . '<br>'; 
}

?>
```

При реализации этого кода выдает ошибку

> Warning mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sources\insert.php on line 7

В чем проблема? Подскажите.

Comment: почему, ну почему никто не пользуется тут поиском а сразу жмёт на  "Задать вопрос"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не дубликат. Он же присваиванием затирает результат вызова, так что нет причин считать, что mysqli_query завершилось с ошибкой.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну значит "вызван опечаткой", а заодно не меняет того факта, что надо в начале искать на ресурсе а не жмакать сразу кнопачки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, надо найти дубликат на `=` вместо `==` - наверняка такой есть.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо 
`if ($result = false)` напишите `if ($result === false)`.
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php